# How to avoid Label in Lightning

Tags: lightning

Questn1:
           Hi I want to display select value without label why because am using select value inside the table. I have added image for more Information [Highlighted through red mark]

Questn 2:
 Visual force page contains selectList.In lightning how can we use select List?

```
  <table >
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
        <th class="head"><I>Action</I></th>
        <th class="head"><I>Object Name</I></th>
        <th class="head"><I>Component</I></th>
        <th class="head"><I>Operator</I></th> 
        <th class="head"><I>Special Operator</I></th>
        <th class="head"><I>Special Operator * Value</I></th>
        <th class="head"><I>Special Operator / Value</I></th>
    </tr>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="c">
    <tr>
        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
                <ui:inputText value="{Action}"  /> </p>   
        </td>

        <td class="cell" >

            <p> 
           <ui:inputSelect  value="{!v.options}" class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" /> 

            </p>
        </td>


        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
                <ui:inputText value="{Component}"  /> </p>   
        </td>


        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
                 **<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item" onchange="{!c.opChange}" >
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                    <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                    <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                    <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
                </lightning:select>**
            </p>   
        </td>

        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
                **<lightning:select name="selectItem" label="Select an item" >
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="*/">*/</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </lightning:select>**

            </p>          
          </td>

        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
                 <ui:inputText value="{!c.specialOperatorValue}"/> 
            </p>
        </td>

        <td class="cell" >
            <p> 
               <ui:inputText value="{!c.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/></p>   
        </td>
    </tr>

    </aura:iteration> 
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid label being displayed on the screen you can assign blank string to label

```
<lightning:select label=""/>
```

Lightning select list version is not currently available and only picklist values are supported .

Answer (score 8):

To avoid label use `variant="label-hidden"`

```
<lightning:select variant="label-hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately setting label to "" still reserves space for the label and causes allignment issues.  Summer 18 added attribute `variant="label-hidden"`, but unfortunately that still reserves the space.  The workaround in the meantime is to add attribute `class="label-hidden"` with CSS:

```
.THIS .label-hidden > label {
    display: none;
}
```